# Accessing half of a register in AArch64 advanced SIMD

Tags: arm, neon, arm64

I am new to AArch64 Advanced SIMD (NEON) and I want to port a AArch32 code to AArch64. In AArch32 if I wanted to access to lower or higher half of a register, I simply used `Dn` instead of `Qn`. For example if I want to access lower 64-bit of `Q12`, I simply referred to `D24`. However, I cannot figure out how can I access to half of a `Vn` register in AArch64. 
I would like to access the higher half of a `Vn` register. So, if I write `Vn.2S`, I assume it gives me the lower half of the register. Is that correct? If yes, how can I access the higher half then?

Comment: When an instruction affects 64-bits out of the 128 in a vector register, the lower 64 are used. A second version of the instruction which ends in "2" (e.g. PMULL2) affects the upper 64-bits of a vector register.

Comment: @BitBank Suppose I want to multiply upper 64-bits of a 128-bits vector register with another 128-bits vector register. I mean I have a 64x128 multiplication. How could I implement that? `PMULL2` affects the upper 64-bits of vectors

Comment: I don't believe there is a 128-bit multiply, but if you want to access the lower 64-bits and the upper 64-bits at the same time, I believe you'll need to move the data into another register using a register index notation (e.g. v5.s[2]).

Comment: @BitBank Yes you're right! 128-bits multiplication doesn't exist. My bad, thank you for your comment I was looking for something like `vn.s[2]` which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Even i tried accessing.
As per the manual, i guess there is no way available to access slot vise.
V0 -> d0 -> s0 has same data.

Whereas in ARM32, Q0 has d0 and d1 and further d0 has s0 and s1.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used pointers to select either the upper or lower half of an Arm Neon vector.

```
uint32x4_t vector = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
uint32x2_t *upperhalf = (uint32x2_t *) &vector[2];
uint32x2_t *lowerhalf = (uint32x2_t *) &vector[0];

*lowerhalf = *upperhalf;
printf("%u", vector[0]);
```

Prints out `3`. This is intrinsically telling the compiler to target either of the double register pairs that make up quad registers. It does not necessarily mean it will be reading or writing to memory when doing this. Instead it sees you want to target the double register directly.

This works with GCC 8, maybe older releases also. Clang 7 gave a "targeting vector..." error message. I have not been able to use the pointer to target indexes in the double register however using it as a regular vector of the datatype it is cast to, either as source or destination has always worked. Below is another example, byte swapping the vector half using the pointer.

```
*lowerhalf = vreinterpret_u32_u8(vrev32_u8(vreinterpret_u8_u32(*lowerhalf)));
```

It is not good practise to target uneven indexes as these overlap registers. I have not tried to see what that does but it will likely shuffle data around to temporary register lanes to complete an operation when doing so. Using pointers in this way has also worked when vectors are members of a struct.